# Backbone/RequireJS model data storage

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I am using Backbone/RequireJS to provide my application with modularization and structure. One thing I am coming up against, and would greatly appreciate some advice in this area.

When a user visits the page, the first thing that happens is some JSON that populates a couple of models. I would like these models to be available where-ever I am in the app, as they contain the data and support for the program. Is it permissible to use `window.modelName`, or do you recommend another/better way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your suggested solution defies the whole purpose of using AMD in the first place.
Define a module (let's call it globals) as such:

```
define(function (require) {
  var globals = function () {
    return {};
  };
  return globals();
});
```

Now, *when you init* you can add values to it:

```
globals = require('globals');
globals.mymodel = new MyModel();
mymodel.fetch();
```

Later, and from any other module, you can access your globals module:

```
globals = require('globals');
console.log(globals.mymodel.get('myattr');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is taking some time for me to think along these lines.

Comment: A pleasure, you can find out more about the rationale if you google for the singleton or module pattern

Comment: I think this project is showing me that I am weaker than I thought on JS itself. Again, thank you!